# ACF Dynamic select values not showing data

Tags: wordpress, select, advanced-custom-fields

This question makes me crazy for almost 2 weeks. I know I am not expert in Wordpress, so I am seeking for help here.

I have create a href that when user click it will go to new page.

```
<a href="./create-class?post=<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">Add Class2</a>
```

This href post the Post id. Url display:

[http://localhost/dev6/create-class/?post=289][1]

create-class page:

At create-class page,I am using GET method to display post id from url

```
$post = $_GET['post'];
```

I have acf form in create-class page for create new post. In this form, there have dynamic select field but the select field not display any data.

```
 <?php      acf_form(array(
          'post_id'   => 'new_post',
          'field_groups' => array(150),
          'post_title'  => false,
          'post_content'  => false,
          'new_post'    => array(
                  'post_type'   => 'classes',
                  'post_status' => 'publish',
                  ),
          'return'    => '%post_url%',
          'submit_value'  => 'Submit',
          //'updated_message'    => 'Course Submit!',
        )); ?>
```

in my function.php I create function for dynamic select:

```
function acf_load_t_first_name2_field_choices($field) {
    global $post;
    //$post = $_GET['post'];
    // reset choices
    $field['choices'] = array();


    // get the textarea value from options page without any formatting
    $choices = get_field('t_first_name',$post->ID);



    // loop through array and add to field 'choices'
    if( is_array($choices) ) {

        foreach( $choices as $choice ) {

            $field['choices'][ $choice ] = $choice;

        }

    }


    // return the field
    return $field;

}

add_filter('acf/load_field/name=t_first_name2', 'acf_load_t_first_name2_field_choices');
```

Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this will work in your create-class template:

```
$post = $_GET['post'];
```

You will need to set something like this up in your functions.php file:

```
function custom_query_vars_filter($vars) {
  $vars[] .= 'post';
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'custom_query_vars_filter' );
```

Then, in your create-class template you can get the variable from the URL like this:

```
$post = get_query_var('post');
```

See if that gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for answer my question. your solution give same result :(

Comment: @user3239674 can you `echo` out the `$post` variable and let us know if its the same variable that is being passed in the URL?

Comment: it show the post id 289 but the select field not showing anything. is there any ways that I can put the `acf_form` in post id loop? sorry, I am really bad at codes